# How to visualize this data from this API call? MLB data, pitches, game information

Tags: javascript, html, css, api

I have been given this API request to use to create a SPA. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rd-astros/hiring-resources/master/pitches.json I'm trying to figure out how best to do this. I have create this SPA as if a coach was using it to review pitches.

`An example end user of this project is a coach who is reviewing these games to look for trends in pitch characteristics for a given pitcher. The user should be able to visualize the data in two ways:

A single-pitch view, with some useful information provided about the selected pitch.
A multi-pitch view, where the user can visualize useful information about multiple pitches at once.

In both views, you should provide some ability for the user to filter the qualifying pitches.`

I have this practice code to work with. I'm trying to figure out how I could filter this data so only data from a certain kind of pitch and pitcher are displayed.

I also want to use this data to display some sort of hot zone chart. [Hot Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcXbq.png)

Comment: There's a lot of value in looking at a data structure and figuring out the best way to process it. You don't want to rob yourself of that learning opportunity (https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems), so start by asking yourself a few questions. How is the JSON structured? Where do you see the data points you need? And then think like a UX developer. What kind of implementation would serve the user best? After you've asked yourself some of these questions, maybe you can clarify your question for others.